# Android UDP Multicast(Server) to C# WPF(Client) sometimes works only with registered multicast ip

Tags: c#, android, wpf, udp, multicast

I am working on a simple app which sends camera byte stream to c# wpf app using UDP Multicast. I am able to achieve this using UDP Broadcasting.

But what I want is to connect it using UDP multicast but its working for me only if I am using registered multicast IP's like "224.0.0.1".

About my Android Code:
I have written a Service for udp connection which I can call from any activity/fragment. This Service has functions for sending images and texts.

**On Camera PreviewCallback**

```
private PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera c) {
            mService.initSocket();
            mService.sendImages(frame);
            c.addCallbackBuffer(frame);
        }
    };
```

**Camera Setup:**

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera_.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(procSize_.width, procSize_.height);
        //p.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
        p.setPreviewFpsRange(targetMaxFrameRate, targetMinFrameRate);
        camera_.setParameters(p);

        PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
        PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(ImageFormat.RGB_565, pixelFormat);
        int bufSize = procSize_.width * procSize_.height * pixelFormat.bitsPerPixel / 8;
        byte[] buffer = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < bufNumber; i++) {
            buffer = new byte[ bufSize ];
            camera_.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);
        }
        camera_.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(cb);
```

**Send Images function:**

```
    while(bRunning) {
      int sessionNumber = 0;
      byte[] buff = msg;
      int packets = (int) Math.ceil(buff.length / (float) DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE);
      for (int i = 0; i < packets; i++) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, localaddress, 11000);
sessionNumber = sessionNumber < MAX_SESSION_NUMBER ? ++sessionNumber : 0;
    if(sessionNumber == packets){
                    bRunning = false;
                 }
           }
    }
```

**About my C# code:**
I have created a UDPMulticast listener:

```
IPAddress multicastIP= IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.1");
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
udpClient.MulticastLoopback = true;
udpClient.Client.Bind(remoteEndPoint);
udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastIP);
byte[] finalBuffer = new byte[80000];
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1048];
                buffer = mUDPClient.Receive(ref ipEndPoint);
                if (buffer[5].Equals(0))
                {
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(finalBuffer);
                    imgPreview.Source = GetImage(stream);
                    finalBuffer = new byte[25000];
                    Array.Copy(buffer, finalBuffer, buffer[4]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Array.Copy(buffer, finalBuffer, buffer[4]);
                }
            }

public BitmapImage GetImage(Stream iconStream)
        {
            var imgbrush = new BitmapImage();
            imgbrush.BeginInit();
            imgbrush.StreamSource = iconStream;
            imgbrush.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            imgbrush.EndInit();
            var ib = new ImageBrush(imgbrush);
            return imgbrush;
        }
```

Even when I am connected I get an error at imgbrosh.EndIt() saying that the image format is not proper because of which even my first image doesn't get created.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I doubt UDP is a good choice for this; to get a large image you would need guaranteed, ordered delivery which UDP does not offer.  I think you need a TCP connection.

Comment: Thanks for replying Hugh. Yes for large images i would need TCP, but what I am doing here is sending android device camera preview to c# application so in that case few packets loss is not going to effect me. Also TCP will make the video stream slower.